# Syntax Error When Using pgbench

Tags: postgresql

I am attempting to obtain some benchmarking data by using **pgbench**, but I am running into a syntax error in the process.  I am running psql v9.6.2 on macOS High Sierra (10.13.2), and consistently receive the same error when using pgbench in the **psql** command-line client, and in PGAdmin IV:

```
syntax error at or near "pgbench"
```

An example command I might run would be:

```
postgres=# pgbench -i -s 2000 [db_name];
```

I'm sure there is something simple that I'm missing here, but the [documentation page](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.6/static/pgbench.html) on pgbench hasn't been too illuminating for me.

Comment: `pgbench` is a command line program, **not** a SQL statement

Answer (score 1):

**pgbench** is a separate command line program shipped with postgres
run it on console, not like a script